# what is this when binding to click event

Tags: reactjs, binding, onclick

I have the following react scripts (index.js & app.js). I'm confused about three problems:

In the index.js script why is {count++} not incrementing whereas {count=count+1} is?  I thought they were the same thing.

In the app.js script I'm confused about what this refers to:

```
<button onClick={this.addOne.bind(this)}>increment</button>
```

I thought the first this referred to App and got the method addOne where as the bind(this) referred to the click event.  Notice below the render() i have var self=this.  If I replace either or both this's in the button statement with self it still works. So what exactly is the bind(this) doing?

Not sure but is the answer since we are calling this on the render function this refers to App.  The first this gets us the method addOne and we then bind this (the App) to this function addOne so we have access to props and state?

If the answer above is on the right tract my third question is why can't I change the addOne function to take as a parameter this and then in the onClick event use:

```
<button onClick={this.addOne(this)}>increment</button>
```

```js
/* index.js */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
var count = 4
ReactDOM.render(<App count={count++}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();


/*app.js */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state={increment:this.props.count}

   }

   addOne(){
      this.setState({increment: this.state.increment+1})
   }

  render() {
  var  self=this
    return (

    <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>


        <p>{this.state.increment}</p>

        <button onClick={this.addOne.bind(this)}>increment</button>
      </div>
    );

  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript functions are first-class citizens and we can pass around functions just like normal variables. for eg: `onClick={this.addOne}` 
Here we are passing `addOne` function as a parameter to onClick event, instructing it  `onclick of element invoke the function passed`

Only problem is that your addOne function implementation contains references to `this`(this.setState).

If you are invoking a method by saying say `a.func()` within func `this` refers to `a`(here func is binded to a). But if you are just calling `func()`, within func() `this` will be undefined. To avoid that you can explicitly bind `func` to `this`.

For eg: `a.func()` is same as `func.bind(a)()`
Now references to `this` inside func will point to `a`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

`this` refers to an instance of the class(which is App object.)

`why is {count++} not incrementing whereas {count=count+1} is? I thought they were the same thing.` This is because count++ will increment the value of count only after using it in current statement. whereas ++count or count+1 will increment it in current statement itself.

if you want to pass self to the addOne function as a variable, your addOne should like this.

```
addOne(self){
 return function() { 
   self.setState({increment: self.state.increment+1})
 }
}
```

Comment: so why can't I pass this into the function?  and any ideas of why count++ doesn't work?

Comment: you can certainly pass this to the function. but you have to stop referring to `this` in `addOne`  method and instead use the parameter passed.

Comment: so I tried <button OnClick={this.addOne(this)}.... with addOne(self){self.setState({increment:self.state.increment+1}) but that doesn't work

Comment: have you modified your function like `addOne(i){
      i.setState({increment: i.state.increment+1})
   }`

Comment: like what?  I get this error message:  Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState    What is causing setState to be called ? It happens before I click on the button

Comment: Oops my bad. above one will cause this error. Because during render itself  it calles addOne. OnClick expects a function. Instead if you try following that should work `addOne(i){ return function() {i.setState({increment: i.state.increment+1})} }`

Comment: using your return function I can call the addOne function without any parameters and then set var j = this. then return function(){j.setState....... works but return function(){this.setState........ does not.  Are there restrictions on using the keyword this that causes this problem?

Comment: yes this is a keyword and within a function it specifically points to object binding to the function.